# Selenium script get "WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools" when use on another PC. Worked fine on my PC

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm writing a script using Selenium to automate some website task. This requires me to attach Selenium to an already manually opened browser. I added `"--remote-debugging-port=1234"` on a Chrome shortcut and used the code below to connect:

```py
debug_port = 1234

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", f"localhost:{debug_port}")

driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

This worked perfectly fine on my PC: I was able to control the browser like a normal Selenium webdriver. But when I tried this on another user's PC, it gave this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools 

(failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)

(Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.92)
```

I already added `"--remote-debugging-port=1234"` on that user's Chrome shortcut as well. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The other user Chrome get stucked when auto updating. It keeps saying to relaunch to finish update but never finished. Hence Selenium is confused about which versions to get.